# How can I share a secret line of text with UIActivityView

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

```
NSString* text=@"Hello world";
NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/"];
//  UIImage * myImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
NSArray* sharedObjects=@[text,myWebsite];
UIActivityViewController * activityViewController=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:sharedObjects applicationActivities:nil];

activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I want to add an extra line of advertised text only after the Post button is pressed. I want to say "Made with NameOfApp"

Comment: You can not share anything without the user noticing. The user does and will always know what they share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. You cannot alter the contents of a `UIActivityView` after instantiating and presenting it. The most details you'll receive from this `UIActivityView`'s completion handler is whether the activity successfully completed or not. You will not have an opportunity to silently alter the message.

If it's important to include the name of your application, include it by default. Users will either leave it in or delete it.